# How can I directly insert JSON using Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose

It seems a bit convoluted to manually define a schema when I'm dealing with JSON all the time.  Is there a way to convert JSON into BSON thereby relieving the developer of the need to manually define schemas each time?

Comment: Are you saying you just want to accept any sort of json data without having a model?

Comment: I'm saying that I would like the model to be automatically derived from the JSON

Comment: The only thing out there in JS is this, and it's really just a proof of concept, not a reliable library. https://gist.github.com/1070514

Comment: My understanding is that mongoose was specifically developed for modelling. If you don't want to do modelling, you should use a mongodb driver/wrapper that doesn't require it, such as mongoskin or mongolia.

Comment: Simply update your mongoose schema to insert an object  `images: {type: Object}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a tool mongoimport to do this

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at node-mongodb-native[1]? It sounds like it might be a better fit for your needs since it doesn't require a predefined schema.

[1] https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native